# Restringir um array limite de caracteres no LIKE

Tags: sql, array

Tenho uma duvida sobre o `LIKE` do T-SQL. 
É possível restringir por um numero de caracteres iguais para verificar quantos endereços começam igual e podem terminar diferente?
Mais ou menos assim:

```
Where Endereco LIKE '[array10caracteres]%'
```

O meu objetivo é chegar a um resultado mais ou menos onde o endereço de uma pessoa é:

> Rua Comandante linhares N 10
>   Rua Comandante linhares LT 8 QD 150

A ideia é que esses dois apareçam com uma contagem ou algo do tipo

Comment: Existem algoritmos que comparam string como a Jaro–Winkler distance (entre outras) , usei uma vez no Oracle e funcionou bem , mas estas comparações são relativas no caso você procura endereços na mesma rua independente do complemento (busca por vizinhos) ?

Comment: Sim... busco vizinhos e pessoas da mesma rua.

Comment: A Jaro do Oracle retorna um valor de 93 para estes dois endereços, trocando o endereço para "RUA COMANDANTE KIRK LT 8 QD 150" fica com 88 , questão de refinar talvez.

Answer (score 4):

Você pode restringir o valor que você usa à esquerda do `LIKE`:

```
WHERE LEFT(Endereco, 10) LIKE ...
```

Comment: Eu tentei isto amigo, porém não deu certo. Eu não quero definir um endereço o que eu quero é que ele pegue sozinho endereços com os 10 primeiros caracteres iguais. Conseguiu entender meu raciocínio?

Comment: Quer comparar todos os endereços da tabela entre si?

Comment: Sim e agrupar em um `count` os que tem os 10 caracteres iguais. Para poder pegar as pessoas da mesma rua porém com números e complementos diferentes, entendeu?

Comment: Com um `GROUP BY LEFT(Endereco, 10)` você consegue contar quantas pessoas têm o mesmo começo de endereço. Porém não conseguiria saber quais são essas pessoas, nem seu endereço completo. Para isso, precisa de uma subquery. Acho que já tem uma explicação sobre isso aqui no site, vou tentar localizar e te passo o link.